# Product attribute as link on other page

Tags: magento

I have product with attribute `address` - where is product places. It is dropdown list. I want this atttribute will be a link on other site page with map and some other info about this address. But when i use html code in editor of attribute options it's not working. At the same time i checked property "Allow HTML Tags on Frontend" - it has "Yes" value. How can i do this?

[image]

Comment: can you show the image where you are trying on ?

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? I tried this and I was surprised that it works.

Comment: @Marius i my case html tags are disappeared after saving, setting "Allow HTML Tags on Frontend" is enabled.

Comment: @Alex: Yes you are right html tag is not saving with the dropdown option that will only save when we enable WYSIWYG editor but WYSIWYG editor will only enable when the attribute is Text Area type .... let me do some research on it...

Comment: @Alex: which version are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how my attribute looks like. and it seams to work:
[image: options]

For the attribute settings I just set to `Yes` `Allow HTML Tags on Frontend` and `Visible on Product View Page on Front-end`. The rest is set to `No`.

Here is how it looks like in the backend when editing a product.
[image]

And here is how looks in the frontend. And the link actually works.

[image]

I'm using CE-1.7.0.2.
Maybe the version is the problem. You can also try reindexing after you add the attribute.

**[EDIT]**
It seams that for 1.9 something changed.
See these lines in the attribute controller `_filterPostData` method:

```
foreach ($data['option']['value'] as $key => $values) {
    $data['option']['value'][$key] = array_map(array($helperCatalog, 'stripTags'), $values);
}
```

You can view them here also: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/AttributeController.php#L167

The filter method looked differently in 1.8 and before:  https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.8/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/AttributeController.php#L153. It didn't have the strip tags on the options. Just the label.

I guess you can try to override the `Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_AttributeController::_filterPostData` method and make it look like it does in 1.8. But I don't know the risks.

Comment: i am using 1.9.0 version and it is not saving the html tag for dropdown attribute value

Comment: @VishalSharma. AHA. I will test on 1.9 and come back with a result.

Comment: I checked that in 1.8.0 and it's working perfectly ... but not in 1.9.0

Comment: we don't need to override the whole function we just need to replace this line  $data['option']['value'][$key] = array_map(array($helperCatalog, 'stripTags'), $values); TO   $data['option']['value'][$key] = $values;

Comment: @VishalSharma. You could do that, but It's not ok. You should never edit the core code. Create your own module for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58321/discussion-between-vishal-sharma-and-marius).